# Emacs PS printing problem

Tags: osx, error, print

I'm running Emacs 29.2 on Mac OS 14.4 on an M1 Mini. I have a Brother HL-L8260CDW series printer.

Normal print commands (`print-buffer`, `print-region`) work fine.

What doesn't work are the `ps-print...` suite of commands. If I run `M-x ps-print-buffer-with faces`, I get this error:

Spooling...done: /usr/bin/lpr: Unsupported document-format “application/postscript”

A *PostScript* buffer is created, if I try to print this buffer with `ps-despool`, I get a similar error.

I added `(require 'printing)` and `(require 'ps-print)` to my init.el. Didn't fix the problem.

I checked variables `printer-name`, value "default". I looked at the CUPS interface, it looks OK, but I didn't change anything in case I really broke something.

These commands used to work, otherwise I wouldn't have bothered to bind `ps-print-buffer-with-faces` to `M-s-b`. My problem could have something to do with upgrading either Emacs to 29, or Mac OS to 14.4.

I'm not sure whether this is an Emacs problem, but I thank the group in advance for pointing me in the direction of a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly Emacs is generating the postscript file and submitting it using the `lpr` program correctly. But `lpr` returns an error. That’s where you should begin your investigation. `lpr` is part of CUPS, so consult the CUPS documentation.

Comment: Thanks, @db48x for your reply. The CUPS documentation is a complete mystery. Can you suggest where I might start looking?